# Simplify function with repeating if/else parts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simplify this function, as there can be multiple `type` of data objcts and for each type there is also a male and a female version.
The number and name of the elements in the objects are always identical.

As you see, most of the code is repeating...

```
function calculate(type, j, value, s) {
    for (var i = j; i > 4; i--) { 
        if (type == 'weight') {
            if (s == 'f') { 
                if (weightFemale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var m = weightFemale[i][0],
                        l = weightFemale[i][1],
                        s = weightFemale[i][2];     
                    return getcalc( m,l,s );
                }
            }
            else {
                if (weightMale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var m = weightMale[i][0],
                        l = weightMale[i][1],
                        s = weightMale[i][2];       
                    return getcalc( m,l,s );
                }               
            }
        }
        else if (type == 'length') {
            if (s == 'f') { 
                if (lengthFemale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var m = lengthFemale[i][0],
                        l = lengthFemale[i][1],
                        s = lengthFemale[i][2],
                    return getcalc( m,l,s );
                }
            }
            else {
                if (lengthMale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var m = lengthMale[i][0],
                        l = lengthMale[i][1],
                        s = lengthMale[i][2],
                    return getcalc( m,l,s );
                }               
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I simplify the if/else-parts for the type and the sex?

Comment: as your code seems to be working code, you might consider asking this on codereview.stackexchange.com. as for the question, making a function for the repeating parts could help a bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on a site like codereview.stackexchange

Comment: Firstly does this code work properly? Because `s = 'f'` needs to be `s == 'f'`.

Comment: Yes. This code will never get into else section because it will set 'f' character to s variable and all the expression will return 'f', which is true, so  you need to write s == 'f', as Spencer Wieczorek noticed.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, Yura Yakym: Updated that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing the same thing to each object , just make your conditionals define a single object reference and only call calculation once.

Something like:

```
var obj;

if (type == 'weight') {
    obj = s == 'f' ? weightFemale : weightMale;
} else if (type == 'length') {
    obj = s == 'f' ? lengthFemale : lengthMale;
}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    var m = obj[i][0],
        l = obj[i][1],
        s = obj[i][2];
    return getcalc(m, l, s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a own function and create a switch

```
switch(type) {
    case "weight":
        getValues();
        break;
    case "length":
        getValues();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself, what are the parts that are very similar? It looks if `.hasOwnProperty()` is true, you get m, l, and s from the array and then call `getcalc()`. Start by extracting that part into a function with the differing pieces being passed in as parameters.

Another pattern is that you're using a particular array based on certain conditions. Getting the array you want can be placed into a function.

Also, not quite related to the question, but you may want to give your variables better names. This makes the code more readable and easier to reason about.

Here's what I came up with:

```
function getArray(type, s){
    if(type == 'weight') {
        return s == 'f' ? weightFemale : weightMale;
    }
    else if(type == 'length') {
        return s == 'm' ? lengthFemale : lengthMale;    
    }
}


function makeCalculation(array, i) {
    if(array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var m = lengthMale[i][0],
            l = lengthMale[i][1],
            s = lengthMale[i][2],
        return getcalc( m,l,s );
    }
}

function calculate(type, j, value, s) {
    for (var i = j; i > 4; i--) { 
        var array = getArray(type, s);
        return makeCalculation(array, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can create function like this:

```
function _getcalc(arr, i) {
    var m = arr[i][0],
    l = arr[i][1],
    s = arr[i][2];
    return getcalc(m, l, s);
}
```

Then you can shorten your function like this:

```
function calculate(type, j, value, s) {
    for (var i = j; i > 4; i--) { 
        switch(type) {
            case 'weight':
                if (s == 'f' && weightFemale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    return _getcalc(weightFemale, i);
                } else if(weightMale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    return _getcalc(weightMale, i);
                }
                break;
            case 'length':
                if (s == 'f' && lengthFemale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    return _getcalc(lengthFemale, i);
                } else if(lengthMale.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    return _getcalc(lengthMale, i);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: need a `return` in `_getcalc()`

Comment: Sure, I've fixed this. Thank you.